# Extra `eecfbba=.@aa` file in sd card

Tags: arduino-mega, spi, sd-card, sd.h

I am doing a project, and I need an SD card. Everything worked well, but after a while when I read the SD card from my PC(Windows 10 64 bit, Intel Core), I found a file called `eecfbba=.@aa`. It's so big that it almost ate up one GB storage of my SD card. But when I tried to open it with notepad, notepad tells me that there is actually no such file, and asks me if I want to create it. I tried to delete it, but file explorer also told me there is no such file. What is it?

This is my code:

```c
#include <ArduinoJson.h>

// Version 0.20.1.19.3.7:
// 2020/01/19, 16:10, button record test, 7th version.

#include <SD.h>
#include <SPI.h>
#include <TMRpcm.h>
#include <Wire.h>
#include "RTClib.h"
//#include <string.h>

RTC_DS1307 rtc;
String strdoc;
char daysOfTheWeek[7][2] = {"su", "mo", "tu", "we", "th", "fr", "sa"};
#define SD_ChipSelectPin 10  // 如果使用 arduino nano 328 可使用Pin4

TMRpcm audio;
void setup() {
  audio.speakerPin = 8;
  Serial.begin(9600);
  pinMode(25, INPUT_PULLUP);
  pinMode(7, INPUT_PULLUP);
  if (! rtc.begin()) {
    Serial.println("Couldn't find RTC");
    while (1);
  }
  if (! rtc.isrunning()) {
    Serial.println("RTC is NOT running!");
    rtc.adjust(DateTime(F(__DATE__), F(__TIME__)));
  }
  else
  {
    Serial.println("rtc started");
  }

  if (!SD.begin(SD_ChipSelectPin)) {
    Serial.println("SD Fail");
    return;
  } else {
    Serial.println("SD OK");
  }

  audio.setVolume(6);
  audio.CSPin = SD_ChipSelectPin;

  StaticJsonDocument<200> doc;
  doc["sensor"] = "gps";
  doc["time"] = 1351824120;
  JsonArray data = doc.createNestedArray("data");
  data.add(48.756080);
  data.add(2.302038);
  serializeJson(doc, strdoc);
}
bool isrecording = false;
bool recordButtonPressed()
{
  return (digitalRead(25) == LOW);
}
bool playButtonPressed()
{
  return (digitalRead(7) == LOW);
}
void loop() {
  delay(200);
  // Below is the formatted datetime.
  DateTime now = rtc.now();
  // Below is the serialized datetime.
  String filename = (String)(now.unixtime() % 10000000) + ".j";
  //  Serial.println(filename);
  if (recordButtonPressed())
    if (!isrecording)
    {
      isrecording = true;
      audio.startRecording("test.wav", 16000, A0);
      Serial.println("stt");
    }
    else
    {
      isrecording = false;
      Serial.println("stp");
      audio.stopRecording("test.wav");
    }
  Serial.println("sdsad991===`=`");
  if (playButtonPressed())
  {
    audio.play("test.wav");
    Serial.println("ply");
  }
  String dataString = strdoc;
  if (!isrecording)
  {
    File dataFile = SD.open(filename, FILE_WRITE);

    if (!dataFile) {
      Serial.println(F("Failed to create file"));
    }
    else
    {
      dataFile.println(dataString);
      Serial.println("Wrote string.");
      dataFile.close();
      Serial.println("Closed file.");
    }
  }
  /* Please ignore this line */
  //  //    audio.play("test.wav"); break;audio.volume(1); break;audio.volume(0); break;audio.stopPlayback(); break;
}
```

P.S. I'm using Mega 2560, so MISO, MOSI, SCK and CS pins are different.(Which is 50,51,52,10).

Edit 2020/1/25, 14:15(Beijing Time) At 1/20 I have bigger problems. There are more and more big files. All of them are the same situation. For details, take a look at this photo(ignore selected files): [Imgur](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mAV1x.jpg) or 咱们中国人上不去imgur，用这个：[File-up（直接下载）](https://www.file-up.org/kbg7y8frdjtl)

Comment: @ jsotola thank you for your quick reply. But now I have bigger problems: there are tons of other files! [Screenshot of my SD card](https://imgur.com/a/6ncCD4T) (P.S. Ignore the selected ones, they're what I want. Focus on the others)

Comment: I want to know whet are they and do I need to do anything?

Comment: don't use String class

Comment: @Juraj thank you I will try that out. But can you please tell me the real reason , why String class would produce such files?

Comment: https://majenko.co.uk/blog/evils-arduino-strings

Comment: Ok, thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Juraj, I fixed the problem. Deleted those files by manually formatting the SD card.

***This is not really the answer, you can see the answer in [this comment](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/71901/extra-eecfbba-aa-file-in-sd-card#comment157026_71901) under the question.***